# Loading csv file and accessing data by row and col using Latex3

Tags: latex3, csv

I want to load data from csv file and later access them.

In C# I would have one `Dictionary<string, int>` for mapping column names to their indexes. And another `Dictionary<string/*PK value*/, string[]/*Row values*/>` for data rows.

```
int pkColumnIndex;
Dictionary<string, int> columns;
Dictionary<string/*PK value*/, string[]/*Row values*/> tbl;

// Accessing data
string GetValue(string pkValue, string columnName)
{
  int columnIndex = columns[columnName];
  string[] rowValues = tbl[pkValue];
  string val = rowValues[columnIndex];
  return val;

  // or short version
  //  return tbl[pkValue][columns[columnName]];
}

// Usage
string v = GetValue("aa", "Val1");
```

This is what I have so far in LaTex using LaTex3 (it is not final as I cannot move further).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
PK,Val1,Val2
aa,John Smith,MyUrlAA
bb,Jane Smith,MyUrlBB
\end{filecontents*}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% Column number of PK. 1-based.
\int_new:N \g_csv_pk_index_int

% Dictionary<pk,csv_line>
\prop_new:N \g_csv_tbl_prop

% Dictionary<column_name,index_1_based>
\prop_new:N \g_csv_header_prop


\cs_new_protected:Nn \csvheader_to_prop:n
{
    % #1 - header line from csv file

}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \csvline_add_to_prop:n
{
    % #1 - line from csv file

    \prop_gput:Nff \g_csv_tbl_prop
        {
            % Split comma separated string and get only the valueN
            % get value of column of PK
            \clist_item:nn { #1 } { \g_csv_pk_index_int }
        }
        {
            % store the entire line as a value of Dictionary<pk,val>
            #1
        }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_gput:Nnn { Nff }

\NewDocumentCommand{\readcsvfile}{mm}
{
    % #1 - file path
    % #2 - pk column name

    % Declare file/stream
    \ior_new:N \l__csv_file_stream
    % Open file
    \ior_open:Nn \l__csv_file_stream { #1 }

    \int_zero_new:N \l__line_count_int
    % Read lines
    \ior_str_map_inline:Nn \l__csv_file_stream
    {
        \int_compare:nNnTF \l__line_count_int = 0
        {
            % Reading the first line
            % Build map of columns
            % \csvheader_to_prop:n { ##1 }

            \int_set:Nn \g_csv_pk_index_int { 1 }
        }
        {
            % Build Dictionary<pk,line>
            % Read and process a line
            \csvline_add_to_prop:n { ##1 }
        }

        \int_incr:N \l__line_count_int
    }
    % Close file
    \ior_close:N \l__csv_file_stream
}

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{ \getcsvvalue }{ mm }
{
    \prop_item:Nn \g_csv_tbl_prop { #1 }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

% Read and load csv data (outside of ExplSyntaxOn)
\readcsvfile{data.csv}{PK}

\begin{document}

\getcsvvalue{aa}{Val1}

\getcsvvalue{aa}{Val2}

\getcsvvalue{bb}{Val1}

\getcsvvalue{bb}{Val2}

\end{document}
```

It can read file, split lines, skip header line, get PK value for each row and populate `\g_csv_tbl_prop`, later access data by PK value.

What is missing is parsing header line to populate `g_csv_header_prop` and later use it to calculate `\g_csv_pk_index_int`; parsing each data line and store `clist` or `seq` as a value of `\g_csv_tbl_prop`; accessing data by PK value and column name.

This is what I have and it is not working:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
PK,Val1,Val2
aa,J\'ohn Sm\'ith,https://text.com/John_Smith/#data
bb,J\'ane Sm\'ith,https://text.com/Jane_Smith/#data
\end{filecontents*}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% Column number of PK. 1-based.
\int_new:N \g_csv_pk_index_int

% Dictionary<pk,csv_line>
\prop_new:N \g_csv_tbl_prop
% Dictionary<column_name,index_1_based>
\prop_new:N \g_csv_header_prop


\cs_new_protected:Nn \csvheader_to_prop:n
{
    % #1 - header line from csv file

    \regex_split:nVN {,} #1 \l_tmpa_seq

    \int_zero_new:N \l__column_count_int
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
    {
        \int_incr:N \l__column_count_int
        \prop_gput:Nff \g_csv_header_prop {##1} {\l__column_count_int}
    }
}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \csvline_add_to_prop:n
{
    % #1 - line from csv file

    \prop_gput:Nff \g_csv_tbl_prop
        {
            % Split comma separated string and get only the valueN
            % get value of column of PK
            \clist_item:nn { #1 } { \g_csv_pk_index_int }
        }
        {
            % store the entire line as a value of Dictionary<pk,val> for now.
            % It is better to split it and store as clist or seq.
            #1
        }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_gput:Nnn { Nff }

\NewDocumentCommand{\readcsvfile}{mm}
{
    % #1 - file path
    % #2 - pk column name

    % Declare file/stream
    \ior_new:N \g_hpcolos_get_tabs_stream
    % Open file
    \ior_open:Nn \g_hpcolos_get_tabs_stream { #1 }

    \int_zero_new:N \l__line_count_int
    % Read lines
    \ior_map_inline:Nn \g_hpcolos_get_tabs_stream
    {
        \int_compare:nNnTF \l__line_count_int = 0
        {
            % Reading the first line
            % Build map of columns
            \csvheader_to_prop:n { ##1 }

            % Calculate PK column index.
            \prop_get:NnN \g_csv_header_prop {#2} \g_csv_pk_index_int
        }
        {
            % Build Dictionary<pk,line>
            % Read and process a line
            \csvline_add_to_prop:n { ##1 }
        }

        \int_incr:N \l__line_count_int
    }
    % Close file
    \ior_close:N \g_hpcolos_get_tabs_stream
}

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{ \getcsvvalue }{ mm }
{
    \prop_get:NnN \g_csv_header_prop {#2} \l_tmpa_int
    \prop_get:Nn \g_csv_tbl_prop { #1 } \l_tmpa_str
    \clist_item:nn \l_tmpa_str { \l_tmpa_int }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

% Read and load csv data (outside of ExplSyntaxOn)
\readcsvfile{1.csv}{PK}


\begin{document}

\getcsvvalue{aa}{Val1}

\getcsvvalue{aa}{Val2}

\getcsvvalue{bb}{Val1}

\getcsvvalue{bb}{Val2}

\end{document}
```

And my real data have names with "'" and urls with "// _ #".